# iOS: memory increase when scrolling in tableView in the FXForms project

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, fxforms

When I create a form with [FXForms](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXForms), it is very fluid, memory is ok. The problem is that the more you scroll down and up, the more memory is increasing which make the scroll very slow, very bad.
I read in [a ticket](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXForms/issues/314) and [another ticket](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXForms/pull/435) that the tableview of that FXForms don't use cells recycling.

How can I find the way to resolve that problem?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForField:(FXFormField *)field
{
    //FIXME: memory leak recycle cells

    //don't recycle cells - it would make things complicated
    Class cellClass = field.cellClass ?: [self cellClassForField:field];
    NSString *nibName = NSStringFromClass(cellClass);
    if ([nibName rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        nibName = nibName.pathExtension; //Removes Swift namespace
    }
    if ([field.mandatory isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        if ([field.mandatory isEqualToString:@"YES"])
        {
            NSString *string = [field.title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
            BOOL isNotEmpty = ![string isEqualToString:@""];
            if (isNotEmpty)
            {
                if (![[string substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:mandatoryCharacter])
                {
                    [field setValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", mandatoryCharacter, field.title] forKey:@"title"];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nibName ofType:@"nib"])
    {
        //load cell from nib
        return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
    }
    else
    {
        //hackity-hack-hack
        UITableViewCellStyle style = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
        if ([field valueForKey:@"style"])
        {
            style = [[field valueForKey:@"style"] integerValue];
        }
        else if (FXFormCanGetValueForKey(field.form, field.key))
        {
            style = UITableViewCellStyleValue1;
        }

        //don't recycle cells - it would make things complicated
        return [[cellClass alloc] initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(cellClass)];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in autoreleasepool and check

e.g:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)cellForField:(FXFormField *)field {@autoreleasepool {}}
```

Comment: @ sachin khaire Hello, I tried it, but it doesn't change the memory increasing...

Comment: Please avoid reuseIdentifier: is to reuse your cellClass and their content. You need to find alternate of reuseIdentifier.thanks